# Text classification: Raw dictionary input and text vectorization

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp

I am working with some text processing using a series of sklearn classifiers. In an [example](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/machine-learning-sentiment-analysis-text-classification-using-python-nltk/) I found on the internet, I have noticed that the input of the classifier is a series of dictionary items:

`({'my': True, 'first': True, 'visit': True, 'was': True, ...}, 'pos')`

`({'wowjust': True, 'wow': True, 'who': True, 'would': True,..}, 'pos')`

These items are passed into a classification model (e.g., sklearn `LinearSVC`). I have found in the sklearn site that in text classification text data are transformed into a vector using some technique e.g., `HashingVectorizer` but I couldn't locate any documentation on how the aforementioned dictionary input is treated. Is it possible to provide some explanation of what procedure is followed in this input case?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html), it tokenizes the text it gets (you can customize the how to tokenize the text, a regex telling what you consider a word and list of stopwords to be omitted), and compute a hash for every token that survives, which is a number between 0 and `n_features` (another parameter of the vectorizer).

Unlike [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer), you are always sure, you have exactly `n_features` features, but you indeed risk hashing collisions.